# The position and size of the buttons are changing?

Tags: ios, swift, button, constraints

I set my background image to "scale to fiil".But buttons are not growing. Their location is changing.Does anyone have advice on this?

[image]

Comment: can you please add some code?

Comment: I did not use code for locations.

Comment: You are doing this on interface ?

Comment: yes, i'm doing on the interface.

Comment: please add ss of that.

Comment: have you applied constraints?

Comment: @YogeshPatel I added ss.

Comment: @KeshuR I'm applying.
But I can not say that I am good at this.

Comment: Hey please add your storyboard constrain interface ss so it can be helpful for us. Thank you @YiğitLuş

Comment: @YogeshPatel i added constraint ss.

Comment: Have you tried this Method layoutIfNeeded() and ClipToBounds = true ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Button size will not increase with respect to the background image. you have to apply constraints with the multiplier of Superview. like Equal Width and Equal Height

Comment: I am trying now. Thanks